# excel vba macro to match cells from two different workbooks and copy and paste accordingly and have to update only the empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

please help me in this..

I have two workbooks Bookone.xlsm and Booktwo.xlsm, bookone will be the source and booktwo is the target excel file.

Bookone and Booktwo has the below data.
[Source and target excel file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHjfD.jpg)

I just need to update the cells which is empty, but all the cells are getting updated including Non empty cells

Output of my VBA script.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ZeZ.jpg)

Thanks in advance.. :)

My Code :

```
Sub UpdateW2()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Workbooks("BookOne.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("BookTwo.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")


For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, -3)
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value.Interior.ColorIndex=8
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching the values from `w1` column `D` in `w2` column `A`. There **all** values will be found, except "Mach7". So **all** values will be updated.

You probably want only update if  `w2` column `C` is still empty. Then you  must check this.

```
Sub UpdateW2()

 Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
 Dim c As Range, FR As Variant

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set w1 = Workbooks("BookOne.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set w2 = Workbooks("BookTwo.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

 For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  FR = Empty
  FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
  If TypeName(FR) <> "Error" Then 'match was found
   If IsEmpty(w2.Range("C" & FR)) Then 'cell in w2 is still empty
    w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, -3)
    w2.Range("C" & FR).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
   End If
  End If
 Next c

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In opposite to `WorksheetFunction.Match`, `Application.Match` will **not** throw an error if no match is found. Instead it will return an error value. So no `On Error...` is needed here if you `DIM` the `FR`as `Variant`. Then you can check `FR` whether it is an error value.